# Carrera Virtuoso Road Pro 2008 Tyre identification

Tags: tire, parts, identify-this-bike

I don't suppose anyone knows the make and model of this tyre? These allegedly came as OEM on all Carrera Virtuoso Road Pro circa 2008, the Black and Blue Road Pro model. This has been bugging me as I cannot find ANYWHERE the model of these tyres, and I found these ultra-grippy compared to any other tyres I've used.

I've done many hours of research online over a couple of days, but I just cannot find any information on these tyres, or even people who sell these.

[image: Possibly Kenda tyres, though I'm unsure.]

Anyone who can help, or anyone with one of these with these tyres, please, please, please help! Thankyou all in advance.

Comment: Tires almost always have some kind of label on the sidewall. Could you post a photo of it?

Comment: This is all I have. I don't actually have this, this is someone elses, not had one of these for years. That's why I'm desperately scrawling over the internet, hehehehe.

Comment: Why do you want to know what brand/model these are? So you can buy some?

Comment: Is the 'someone else' someone you know? Or did you just find a random picture of the bike on the Internet?

Comment: This is the only photo I can find on the internet that shows it. Not someone I know. And yes, I'm looking for the make and model of the tyre to purchase, as well as advise a friend of mine to buy these.